# New Windows focus issue JavaScript and C#

Tags: javascript, browser, popup

I have below code which I am using to open a new window up on buttonclick. I am executing below code in button click event :  New windows opens up but it does not focus, it just goes behind the main page....  please how can I fix this issue....

```
         protected void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

int activeTab = pgSearchFrm.ActiveTabIndex;

string sel = this.ddlFields.SelectedValue;

string url = "\\ATPrintView.aspx?SearchID=" + Convert.ToString(activeTab) + "&Col=" + sel + "&Val=" + txtFields.Text;

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Open", "window.open('" + url + "','_blank','height=500,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,titlebar=no').focus();", true);
    }
```

Comment: your code works fine on ie 10 , chrome 23 , the popup opend above the main page -- which browser do u use ??

Comment: @Mahmoud I am using IE 9